# Windows subsystem for Android. Passing parameters from console command

Tags: android, windows, adb

I have developed a simple android app that accepts parameters from ADB. I have installed this application on WSA and It is working fine. My problem is that I do not know how can I launch application passing parameters from the command line. The following command opens my android application (without parameters).

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForAndroid_8wekyb3d8bbwe\WsaClient.exe /launch wsa://com.myproject.testparameters
```

I have tried to launch something like this in order to get help from WsaClient but it does not work.

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\MicrosoftCorporationII.WindowsSubsystemForAndroid_8wekyb3d8bbwe\WsaClient.exe /help
```

How can I solve it? Thank you.

EDIT:

I launch my Android app from ADB as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

[image]

I need to do the same thing from Windows Subsystem for Android using command Line.

Comment: What "parameters" are you talking about? Android apps only accept Intents with data as "parameters". Please edit your question and include the code part where you accept parameters.